# A C# IDE for Fedora 29 on ARM64 machine

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, arm, fedora

We are porting our C# application (.Net Core) to Fedora 29 on ARM64 machines.
I am tasked with building our developing environment.
Currently I have a remote desktop with VNC and the next thing I need is an IDE.
So far I tried installing:

- MonoDevelop - Opened a window, showed an error message and allowed reporting and exited.
- Rider - Showed "Loading solution..." and failed to run the Resharper Code Service (something with a file with x86_64 in its path not found).
- VSCode - From https://code.headmelted.com/#linux-install-scripts that wrote: No match for argument: code-oss Error: Unable to find a match Visual Studio Code install failed.

Any other ideas or advice?

I can keep combating these 3 and maybe open bugs but it doesn't seem like a very fruitful path so far. Is there something that just works?

ARM64 servers seem to be the future but without a decent development environment it will be difficult to develop applications that will run on them.

Comment: Why do you need an IDE on your target platform? You can write,debug and compile your app on a Windows 10 x64 PC and run it no problem on a Linux ARM64 PC, as long as the same or compatible versions of the .NET Core runtime are used

Comment: And if you don't want to do that, you can still do you build and test cycle on your desktop (I do it on Fedora x86_64) and then rely on the .NET Core command line sdk to build/run your application on arm64.